# Sync Azure AD users to SQL Server Users Table

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-3.1

What is the best approach for syncing users between Azure AD and an Azure-hosted SQL DB? I would like users to be able to authenticate to the Azure site and then the .Net core v3.1 application will use the authenticated Azure AD user Id to insert table row data based on the authenticated user ID. I am sure this is pretty straight forward but some articles or advice would be helpful as this is my first stab at hosting an Azure .Net Core solution with Azure AD and website SQL DB.

My site currently authenticates users that I've added to Azure Active Directory and I have the tenant connecting and working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want users to be able to only see or add data based on their authentication?  Or do you only want the app to insert the data of the user like an automated process?

If the first option, consider [Row-level Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security?view=sql-server-ver15)

If the second option you need to add permissions for all users to the DB then its like any other connection.  Connect to the DB using AAD then you can insert data under that user